# Haskell eagerly evaluates trace when there are constant values in lambda?

Tags: haskell

I was playing around with Continuation Passing Style with Haskell, and wrote the following:

```hs
import Debug.Trace

maxcps xx k = aux xx k
  where aux [] k' = trace (show "Base case") k' 0
        aux (1:xs) k' = k 1
        aux (x:xs) k' = aux xs (\res -> k' (trace ((show xs) ++ " and " ++ show res) (max x res) ))

main :: IO()
main = maxcps [2,3,4,5] print
```

That yields the following:

```
"Base case"
[] and 0
[5] and 5
[4,5] and 5
[3,4,5] and 5
```

Which is the order I would expect (I think?) based on the fact that the continuations should get called in reverse order starting from the base case, unwinding from there.

However, if I just modify it ever so slightly to, say, instead of `show res` I change it to some constant like `show 1` as seen here:

```
trace ((show xs) ++ " and " ++ show "Hello!")
```

Then I get the opposite order being printed:

```
"Base case"
[3,4,5] and 1
[4,5] and 1
[5] and 1
[] and 1
```

I'nm confused on why this is happening—I would expect the first result since in a language like JavaScript, nesting callbacks will defer the execution of `console.log` statements until the body of the callback is run, but here it seems like in the second case it prints immediately as the recursive calls get made (so the lambda expression hasn't even been called yet). Is this a correct observation, and what's happening exactly to cause this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is tricky to explain, but is a consequence of laziness.

When `\res -> ...` is called, `res` is not fully evaluated, yet, but is an unevaluated expression involving some `trace` calls. When you use `trace (.... ++ show res)` you force `res` to be evaluated, triggering the `trace` calls it has inside, which are printed *before* the outer traces.

In other words, the evaluation of

```
trace ((show xs) ++ " and " ++ show res) (max x res)
```

performs, usually in order:

- the (full) evalution of `xs`
- the evaluation of `res` (which triggers the inner `trace` calls)
- the printing of the trace message
- the evaluation of `max x res`, which triggers:

  - the evaluation of `x`
  - the evaluation of `res` (no-op, it's already been evaluated earlier)

Instead,

```
trace ((show xs) ++ " and " ++ show 1) (max x res)
```

performs:

- the (full) evalution of `xs`
- the printing of the trace message
- the evaluation of `max x res`, which triggers:

  - the evaluation of `x`
  - the evaluation of `res` (which *now* triggers the inner `trace` calls)

So, roughly put, the former expression prints the `trace` message before the inner `trace` calls in `res`, while the latter uses the other order. This causes the `trace` messages to appear reversed.